# Google cloud lifecycle doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried to apply rule on my bucket using gsutil according to:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/lifecycle

I was even able to get the new rule applied to my bucket:

```
gsutil  lifecycle get  gs://testbucket24/
```

And return by this:

```
{"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"age": 7}}]}
```

The issue is that i waited 72 hours , and still all the objects (which created 3 months ago) are still there.

more info:

- I think i have the permission because I succeed to set and get the rule
- Multi-Regional class bucket
- I enabled the access log for this bucket,still get nothing as no action is started

bucket details:
Multi-Regional class

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior?  According to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#behavior objects may not be deleted right away.

Comment: Some of the files were deleted ,but some of them still there even 5 days after their expiration time.I can live with it,but 5 days is too much

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue, but with the age set to 180 days. I have objects that are over a year old that have yet to be deleted. I don't have versioning enabled and I set the lifecycle rule a week ago.